# Why the ArrayList change its hashcode after insert the data?

Tags: java, copy, hashcode

Well, in my opinion, the hashCode() of an object could be the same thing of the object address as in C++, so I expected the hashCode of the object remain the same before and after insert the data.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by charlie on 2015/12/11.
 */
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(1024);
        a.add(0, 1);
        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
        a.add(1, 2);
        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
    }
}
```

but it seems it output a different value, so which means after insert a value, the new list object is a deep copy value of the original one?

Comment: _in my opinion_ What are you basing your opinion on? What does the javadoc say?

Comment: hashCode isn't the address, but the calculated hash value of the object's content

Comment: In general, mutating an Object will modify its hash code. It is technically possible (though incredibly unlikely given a decent hash function) that you might transform it in such a way that the hash code doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hashCode` isn't the object's address, but the calculated hash value of the object's content. Refer to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for more information

If you want to compare and check if it is the same object then you can use `==` operator, which checks the reference.

Comment: Then how can I make sure before or after the insert, the list object is still the same object, not a deep copy one?

Answer (score 2):

According to Javadocs , the hashcode of a List will be calculated based on the individual objects hash code in it. So whenever you add an element to the List, this is going to affect the hashCode of the List directly.

Refer to the below documentation. To calculate the hashCode, it is iterating through each element

---

int hashCode()
Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
  int hashCode = 1;
  **for (E e : list)**
      **hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());**

This ensures that list1.equals(list2) implies that list1.hashCode()==list2.hashCode() for any two lists, list1 and list2, as required by the general contract of Object.hashCode().

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

As per the java documentation, the `hashCode` of a list is affected by the elements that are being added in the list. So the `hashCode` value of a list before and after adding an element into it is different.

Following is the code that Java uses to calculate the `hashCode` of a list:

```
int hashCode = 1;
  for (E e : list)
      hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

Here `E` is the type of elements in the list (`List<E>`)

So it is clear from the above calculation that `hashCode` generation is also dependent on the `hashCode` of the element that is being added to the list.

This is the reason that you are getting different value of `hashCode` after adding another element to the list.